# jquery dialog not load iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<div id="dialog">
      <iframe id="myIframe" src=""></iframe>
    </div>

    <style>
      #myIframe{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>

function showModalSettings(id){
          alert(id);
          $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "fade",
            hide: "fade",
            modal: true,
            open: function (ev, ui) {
              $('#myIframe').src = 'https://www.onet.pl';
            },
            height: '600',
            width: '800',
            resizable: true,
            title: 'Settings'
          });
          $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        }

showModalSettings(12);
```

I need to open in the jquery dialogbox https://www.onet.pl (in iframe).
The current code shows me the dialogbox correctly - but without the onet.pl website. Iframe is empty

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery we use the `attr()` method to modify the attributes of an HTML element.

Your code after the fix will looks like this:

```js
function showModalSettings(id){
  alert(id);
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: "fade",
    hide: "fade",
    modal: true,
    open: function (ev, ui) {
      //$("#myIframe").src = "https://www.onet.pl";
      $("#myIframe").attr("src", "https://www.onet.pl");
    },
    height: '600',
    width: '800',
    resizable: true,
    title: 'Settings'
  });
  $('#dialog').dialog('open');
}

showModalSettings(12);
```

```css
#myIframe{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="dialog">
      <iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Read more about the `attr()` from the following link: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

**Side Note:** next time please reveal the libraries or frameworks you're using (e.g. jQuery UI in this question) , this help whoever want to answer your question.